# SSH2 Python How To Recognize When File Is Directory

Tags: python, ssh2

I am converting my python program from paramiko to ssh2.  I have succeeded in authenticating and I can get a directory listing.  Where I am stuck is as I process through the directory listing how do I recognize whether the "file" is a directory or a file.  I see the attributes but of those I can only see atime being something I will want to use (to know how old the file is).  Once I have done the opendir and readdir (and so have a listing of files) how do I recognize whether each is a file or a directory?

When I do the readdir I am returned:

- Length of filename
- filename
- attributes

  - atime
  - filesize
  - flags
  - gid
  - mtime
  - permissions
  - uid

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used [ssh2-python](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/ssh2-python) myself but I would say to check the contents of `flags`. According to the [library's documentation](https://ssh2-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sftp.html) (as suggested by @NullPointerException) the possible values are:

> LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFMT
>   Type of file mask
>
> LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFIFO
>   Named pipe (fifo)
>
> LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFCHR
>   Character special (character device)
>
> LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR
>   Directory
>
> LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFBLK
>   Block special (block device)
>
> LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFREG
>   Regular file
>
> LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFLNK
>   Symbolic link
>
> LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFSOCK
>   Socket

I would say `flags` is a bit field and you have to check if certain flag is "on" or not with a bitwise operator, for example, to check it it's a directory:

```
flags & LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR == LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR
```

Comment: Apparently it's called `LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR` in ssh2-python: https://ssh2-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sftp.html

Comment: I did find references to those but I can't seem to figure out how to translate the flags attribute (an example being 15) in order to figure out what I need.

Comment: I have the above code but it is not recognizing the entry is a directory
loc1 is a tuple consisting of:

    `from ssh2.sftp import LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR
    from ssh2.session import Session
    if loc1[2].flags & LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR == LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR:
                continue`

    `0 = {int} 7
    1 = {str} '.config'
    2 = {SFTPAttributes}
           atime = {long}
           filesize = {long} 4096
           flags = {long} 15
           gid = {long}
           mtime = {long}
           permissions = {long}
           uid = {long}`

Comment: sorry about the poor formatting - I tried but can't seem to get it to format cleanly

Comment: Haven't used ssh2 myself, so I'm just guessing. Why don't you update your question adding the code you are using?

Answer (score -1):

```
 for i in sftp.opendir(remote_path).readdir():
     print(i[1],i[2].permissions,LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR,
            i[2].permissions&LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IFDIR)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).